# AccountManager.removeAccount deprecated

Tags: android, accountmanager

A couple of years ago I wrote an app that has an AccountManager. Now I'm re-organizing and cleaning up the code and I realized that

```
AccountManager.removeAccount(Account account, AccountManagerCallback<Boolean> callback, Handler handler)
```

is deprecated.

The documentation says that you have to use this method instead

```
AccountManager.removeAccount(Account account, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler)
```

But the problem is that I need API 22 or grater to use it, and my app is API 14 or grater, so here's the question:

What can I do to use a non-deprecated method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check which API is installed on the phone in use and use the appropriate SDK based on that.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {
    // use new account manager code
} else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    // use old account manager code, the above comment will omit the warning.
}
```

Comment: Alredy tried that, the problem still remains. Android Studio keeps signaling me that the method is deprecated.

Comment: @ParKein I have updated my answer with `//noinspection deprecation`, you can safely add that since you are explicitly checking the build version and using the newer version if it's available.